# java swing and android

Tags: java, android, swing

Hello guys coding newbie here. I've just finished basics of Java and some multithreading techniques then started learning some Java SWING coding. At the same time I have started Android which I found more interactive and fun to learn and the fact that it uses Java meant I did not have to learn it all over again.

So when I was learning the two simultaneously, I found out that the construction of Android application and Java SWING applets are very similar. So simple stuff like getting responses of the button seemed to be exactly the same for the two (I guess it's because they use the same language). Are they completely the same?

Also, although Android uses Java, does it have some of its own variations in usage of Java that makes it different from Java language itself?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is using java as a coding(native) language , there is no difference, but they've removed some packages in the android api because they might not needed in Mobile development and they've included some of their own.

Android applications are different from Swing application in terms of platforms and their scope.

Android applications are designed more in .xml files, it has different machanism (like generating ids specified in xml to R.java etc). But the basic java with which you are accessing resource is same

Answer (score 0):

Swing wasn't designed for a touch based constrained environment so it just couldn't fit into mobile. Android is actually radically different to Swing in many regards e.g. `Activity`.

I'd suggest checking out [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) (my employer) which allows Android/iOS development and is more similar to Swing. Codename One has its roots as a Swing clone designed for mobile that we built at Sun Microsystems.